# Parsing this kind of json using retrofit

Tags: android, json, parsing, retrofit, retrofit2

I would like to parse this kind of data using retrofit library.

```
Json
{
   slots” 
  {
    “123”: [
            {
            “an”: ”yy”
            “pa”:”ya”   
            },
            {
            “an”: ”shjs”
            “pa”:”dfdk” 
            },
            {
            “an”: ”mdm”
            “pa”:”dgm,d”    
            },
        ],
    “456”: [
            {
            “an”: ”yy”
            “pa”:”ya”   
            },
            {
            “an”: ”shjs”
            “pa”:”dfdk” 
            },
            {
            “an”: ”mdm”
            “pa”:”dgm,d”    
            },
        ]

}
```

}

These "123" , "456" are dynamic. What would be written in @SerializedName when we want to create POJO using JSON for this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this --

```
  @SerializedName("slots")
    @Expose
    private Map<String, List<YourModel>> slot;
```

Where `YourModel` will be designed according to this structure -

```
           {
             “an”: ”mdm”
             “pa”:”dgm,d”    
            }
```

Comment: This I have already done. Now I want to get another hashmap to get key as "an", "pa" and values as "mdm" etc. How to achieve taht?

Comment: I have created different POJOs for this .

Answer (score 0):

I think that is better to structure your json without dynamic keys (KISS).
You could use an array and use this dynamic field as a value for a key. Here's an example:

```
{
"slots": [
    {
      "name": "123",
      "key1": "value1",
      "key2": "value2"
    },
    {
      "name": "456",
      "key1": "value1",
      "key2": "value2"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: I cannot change the JSON